# how to check from which file or code any specific html element being created

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 1 html file , in this file i have added many JavaScript files . when i run html file title title tag is being create automatic in  my html file.

I do not want  in my html file. how i can stop this? 
Or how i can find from which JavaScript file its being created automatic.

i have downloaded some projects from internet for learning i am beginner

i tried to know via inspect element but am failed
i do not want no title show in my html file. i am not able to delete from html page as its not present in my html static page

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title> this title element i dun want in my html page </title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what's written in the browser's title bar using the javascript command

```
document.title = "my title";
```

So I'd recommend searching you're files for **document.title**

Comment: document.title saved my life i will make its accept after six min thanks sir

Comment: Great - glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

use the below javascript command and you can change the title with this command

```
document.title = "Your page title";
```